# Triggering a python script in one container from an event in another container

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have a few docker containers running in a docker network (I am using docker compose). In container A I am running a python script which does an API call on a remote server. If the API call fetches a specific value, I want to run a python script in container B.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I am using python 3.6

Thanks

Comment: Run a Flask server or similar in container B and trigger it via HTTP.